# Frontend на русском minishop2 modx

Tags: modx, локализация, revo, minishop2

Подскажите возможно ли перевести на русский minishop2 в modx без программирования. Чтобы была[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Так же использую msearch

Answer (score 1):

Для каждого из компонентов minishop2 и mSearch есть соответствующие переводы всех выделенных строк на русский язык. Смотреть нужно в Пространство имен (Lexicons), в верхнем меню админки справа под "шестеренкой".

Но скорее всего у вас в системных настройках сайта задано использование английского языка, переключите (параметр cultureKey) его на русский и словари русского языка будут использованы для компонентов.

Comment: дело было в cultureKey

Comment: Да, получилось. Именно таким образом. Спасибо!